# C# EF Code First Deploy to Godaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having issues deploying my app to godaddy hosting using EF code first. I dont want my app to create the database since the database already exists.

So I read some posts on here and placed this in the constructure:

```
Database.SetInitializer<myContext>(null);
```

Now I get a permission error writing to the temp file.

Anyone had a successful experience deploying this to godaddy shared hosting?

When the project used Model first and edmx files it was deployed fine.

I was able to get this to work right after posting this..

All I had to do was move:

```
Database.SetInitializer<myContext>(null);
```

to the global.asax Application_Start

Comment: I'll be interested to see how this plays out. I've never been able to get EF to work with GoDaddy shared hosting because of trust levels.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what's the server error you are receiving.

setting db initializer to null should work fine. I have tried that. If you post the exception, we can probably find out why exactly that happening

Answer (score 0):

You should use a generated database from the development and remove the database initializer from your code. From my experience, I always got a problem if I didn't remove the database initializer.

I've faced kind of problem before. I am using a different hosting site though. I deployed my MVC 3 Code First app back then. When I deployed the app, I didn't remove the database initializer, so the app drop the database and try to create it again. But when it create the database, it got a permission error. The problem is, the database is actually dropped in the server but in the hosting site cpanel, it is still exist. I send a ticket to the support, and problem solved.